# Kotlin parent and child class initialization order

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-view

I have a view `SubEpoxyRecyclerView`, that is a subclass of `EpoxyRecyclerView`, my parent class. When this view is initialized, the superclass, `EpoxyRecyclerView` calls method `setItemSpacingPx(Int)` in the constructor body.

When this method is called, none of my class variables are initialized! App crashes on line `itemDecorator.pxBetweenItems` stating that  `itemDecorator` is null which is not possible

Subclass (Kotlin):

```
class SubEpoxyRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
    : EpoxyRecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val itemDecorator: Decor = Decor()
    private val someInt: Int = 5
    private var someBoolean: Boolean = true

    override fun setItemSpacingPx(spacingPx: Int) {
        // Called from superclass. Debug: itemDecorator is null, 
        // someInt is 0, someBoolean is false

        removeItemDecoration(itemDecorator)
        itemDecorator.pxBetweenItems = spacingPx

        if (spacingPx > 0) {
            addItemDecoration(itemDecorator)
        }
    }
}
```

SuperClass (Java - Library):

```
public class EpoxyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
  public EpoxyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    if (attrs != null) {
      TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.EpoxyRecyclerView,
          defStyleAttr, 0);
      setItemSpacingPx(a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.EpoxyRecyclerView_itemSpacing, 0));
      a.recycle();
    }

    init();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That's pretty normal. The initialization order is

1. Parent class
2. Child class

Take a look to this example to understand why your code is not working:

```kotlin
open class Parent {
  init { print("parent ") } 
}

class Child : Parent() {
  init { print("child ") } 
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  Child() 
}
```

According to the example above, the main method prints at first "parent ", then it prints "child". In your case the variables of the SubEpoxyRecyclerView class aren't initialized because the class itself gets initialized once the initialization of EpoxyRecyclerView is completed.